# Minimal ideals of localizations

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, localization

If $R$ is a commutative ring with identity and $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$. >Is it true that there is a correspondence between the minimal ideals of $R$ and those of $R_P$?

I know that if $S$ is a multiplicative subset of $R$, then all ideals of the localization $S^{-1}R$ are extended ones. Now, let $I$ be a minimal ideal of $S^{-1}R$, then $I=I^{ce}$. If $I_0$ is an ideal contained in $I^c$, then, $I_0^e$ would be contained in the minimal ideal $I^{ce}=I$, and equality holds between them....

Could anybody give any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Consider: what should happen to minimal ideals not contained in P under localization?

Comment: What is definition of "minimal ideals of R"? Do u mean minimal *prime* ideals of R?

Comment: @user1 the user has been asking lots of questions about socles. No doubt he means the normal meaning of minimal ideal (minimal nonzero)